# Command to display 2 rows at a time from one table?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with 3 rows and 4 columns with different parameters as we can see below:

```
Column1    Column2   Column3
111         data1     124
233         data3     147
254         data4     154
212         data2     100
```

By using select command

```
select * from Tablename where Column = 124;
```

I am getting the 1st rows values from the table as below:

```
Column1    Column2   Column3
111         data1     124
```

I want to show 2 rows at a time, by using same select command as below

```
Column1    Column2   Column3
111         data1     124
212         data2     100
```

Can anyone tell me the command to select the 2 rows from the table?

Comment: mysql or Oracle DB?

Comment: Removed mysql tag.

Comment: What is the logic behind your expected result?

Comment: You should explain the logic behind your need to help people to help you. As far as we know, you may want to get two random rows, which could not be a great business logic...

Comment: Add another row to the table, (250, 'data4', 124), and adjust the expected result accordingly.

Comment: Saying 'first row' or 'first 2 rows' means nothing. You need to say what rules are applied to the DATA to qualify any two particular rows as being first. Your select example is also wrong as I assume it should be column3 (I don't like assumptions; they bite).

Comment: mysql and plsql tags are back. It can't be both. What is your DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

If this is Oracle 12c, you can use the new [`fetch first n rows`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) syntax:

```
with demo (column1, column2, column3) as
     ( select 111, 'data1', 124 from dual union all
       select 233, 'data3', 147 from dual union all
       select 254, 'data4', 154 from dual union all
       select 212, 'data2', 100 from dual )
select * from demo
order by column3, column1
fetch first 2 rows only;
```

I don't know MySQL but a quick search suggests

```
select ... 
from  sometable 
order by ...
limit 2
```

Then again you haven't said which two rows you want so I could be way off.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select top 2 * from Tablename where Column3>=124 order by Column3
```

Or in Oracle:

```
select * from Tablename where Column3>=124 and rownum < 3;
```

Comment: Does Oracle really support `top`?

Comment: select * from Tablename where Column3>=124 order by Column3 limit 2

Comment: @Ravi. `Column3>=124` wont bring 100 as output. Thats wrong. OP just want top 2 rows for which just adding the condition rownum <3 should work,

Answer (score 0):

You have to maintain `order` and use `rownum`. Something like

```
select t.*,rownum from
(select * From your_table 
order by column1) t
where rownum <=2;
```

Change `rownum <=` to any integer depending on your expected output.

Here is **[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9055238d4ac73c294efc013b423ccb3b)**

> Explanation: Reason to use `order by` in inner query is that you
>   cannot guarantee that database will return the result in the same
>   order you have inserted. So with hard `order by` you are forcing inner
>   query to display output in the order you want. Then use `rownum` on
>   the resultset to get your expected output.